# Jupyterlab on Dataproc -- 403 error - Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I got an error when try to launch Julyterlab on Dataproc. it shows 403 error - Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Any idea what would be the issue?

[Error screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5ADm.png)

[Error screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn6XR.png)

The glcoud command as follow:
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create 
--enable-component-gateway
--bucket 
--region asia-southeast1
--zone asia-southeast1-c
--master-machine-type n1-standard-2 --master-boot-disk-size 500
--num-workers 2 --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 --worker-boot-disk-size 500
--image-version 1.5-debian10 --optional-components ANACONDA,JUPYTER
--scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
--project

Comment: How did you create the cluster? gcloud command would be helpful.

Comment: Hello @Dagang,  here is the gcloud command I used: gcloud beta dataproc clusters create cluster-8a69 
--enable-component-gateway 
--bucket data-processing-2 
--region asia-southeast1 
--zone asia-southeast1-c 
--master-machine-type n1-standard-2 --master-boot-disk-size 500 
--num-workers 2 --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 --worker-boot-disk-size 500 
--image-version 1.5-debian10 --optional-components ANACONDA,JUPYTER 
--scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' 
--project lucky-reactor-294323

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a notebook under the root directory. Do it under `GCS` or `Local Disk`.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought it was some firewall rule. It was just need to click into GCS or local disk then you should be able to create a ipynb already. Thanks a lot cyxxy!